# How to resolve liquibase error Cannot find base path '/db/changeLog-master.xml'

Tags: maven, liquibase

I have little problem with liquibase. It return me Cannot find base path '/db/changeLog-master.xml'. My project layout is here :
[image]

When I tried to run mvn liquibase:update, it return this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.8.4:update (default-cli) on project crdb: Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.SetupException:
 Cannot find base path '/db/changeLog-master.xml' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: I also tried to add ${project.basedir} to <changeLogFile>${project.basedir}/db/changeLog-master.xml</changeLogFile>. It also complains, Cannot find base path 'C:/Users/pkostrou/IdeaProjects/crdb2/db/changeLog-master.xml', but path to file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

by default liquibase looks into classpath. You can move your db folder in project resources.

Another solution is to explicit a file path in the pom.xml

Eric

Answer (score 0):

It helps when I upgrade Liquibase on 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '/' at the beginning of the path should help.